# getProductUrl() taking url without giving any url in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, url

I have a custom product page and have a button too on that page below the product. I added a link on the product and the link is

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
```

so When I'm clicking on this link the page is redirecting to **"product_name.html"** . So my question is, where would i find this **"product_name.html"** or is there any way that I could add a custom page on that link and edit that page according my need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [url rewrites](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/search_seo/seo-url-rewrite-custom-create.html): 
Go to `Catalog>URL Rewrite Managment` and add a URL Rewrite for product. It will walk you though and then in the last step you need to modify the *Request Path* (this will be your custom **prodcut_name.html**), click save and you have your custom url added to your product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $product->getUrlPath() instead of $product->getProductUrl().